# If each theorem in intuitionistical is instantion of axiom ?

Tags: logic

I consider intuiniotistical logic in following form:  (axioms):
(1) $\phi\to (\psi\to\phi)$
(2) $(\phi\to (v\to \psi)) \to ((\phi\to v)\to (\phi\to v))$
Is it correcto to say that each theorem of this logic is instantion of axioms (1) and (2) ?

Comment: The two above axioms are intuitionistically *valid*: correct. But to say that "each theorem of this logic is instantion of them" is not correct... In any case, they are not enough to derive all intuitionistically valid formulae (they do not form a *complete* set of axioms).

Comment: Should (2) $(\phi\to (v\to \psi)) \to ((\phi\to v)\to (\phi\to v))$ be $(\phi\to (v\to \psi)) \to ((\phi\to v)\to (\phi\to \psi))$ (with the last $v$ changed to a $\psi$)?

Comment: Yeah, you are right.